# Using [fields] and [field-properties] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have:

- [419 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields+-field-properties) tagged only as [fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields) which has a tag wiki excerpt of:

> In GIS, Fields, also known as attributes, contain information about
>   features.

- [35 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-properties+-fields) tagged only as [field-properties](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-properties) which has no usage guidance
- [11 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields+field-properties) tagged as both [fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields) and [field-properties](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-properties)

Do we need both the [fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields) and [field-properties](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-properties) tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A case could be made to separate "fields" questions into those about field values (for which there is no tag), and those about field properties.

However, in general, I think we should be aiming for fewer rather than more tags, and looking for places where existing tags can be rationalized, so a simple tagging scheme where questions involving field values and field properties both get tagged as [fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields) is more appealing to me than proposing disambiguation.

I suggest that we make [field-properties](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-properties) a synonym of [fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields) *for our tagging purposes*.

---

Furthermore, as [commented by @AndreSilva](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4960/using-fields-and-field-properties-tags#comment9471_4961) and I *think* supported by a [comment from @Midavalo](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4960/using-fields-and-field-properties-tags#comment9470_4961), I propose that tags [attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attributes), [field-properties](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-properties) and [fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields) all be made synonyms of a new composite tag [fields-attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fields-attributes).

Comment: I think you're right.  And possibly a tag for "field values" could use the "attributes" tag instead

Comment: Maybe [tag:fields] should be synonymized into [tag:attributes] as well.

Comment: Maybe we should just roll up fields, attributes, field-properties and attribute-tables into a `fields-attributes` composite tag?

Comment: I think [attribute-table] is a different subject as explained by @Midavalo in https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/do-we-need-both-attributes-and-attribute-table-tags/4825#4825. Apart from that, I like the idea of having [fields-attributes] as a composite tag for [tag:fields], [tag:field-properties] and [tag:attributes].

Comment: Two tags in this space is better than four but I do think the fields/field-properties/attributes and attribute-tables topic spaces are close enough for the level of granularity that we often seek to achieve here.